# Is there a way see if associated entities have been deleted. MSCRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have a feature in our system where the unit tests have been passing for the passed year.

Since yesterday, they are failing and when looking into those unit tests, it seems the unit tests should never have passed because the associating entities are just not there.

My question is whether there is a audit trail for when someone deletes an entity connected to another entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate to `Settings - Auditing - Audit summary view` you will be able to see all the entries of Audit including Delete action for all the entities across the CRM system.

Click on Enable/Disable filters, then apply the filter whatever you want like Event, Entity, Date, etc to drill down & see the desired data.

[image]

[Read more](https://cobaltcare.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/208473336-Audit-Summary-View?mobile_site=true)